# Iterar y actualizar todos los documentos de una colección de mongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, update, pymongo

Para poder utilizar la función de autocompletar necesito extraer datos en las rutas de posición (nota: posición 0 en la matriz de resultados) para todos mis documentos en mi base de datos MongoDB.

Intenté

```
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/ifresearch?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
>>> collection = client.test.sephora_backup3
>>> for x in collection.find():
...     x["name"] = x['q0']['Results'][0]['Name']
```

Pero no parece salvarlo en MongoDB Atlas

Tambien intenté lo que encontré en [codepoc.io](https://www.codepoc.io/blog/mongodb/5679/update-all-documents-in-a-collection-using-pymongo-in-mongodb):

```
>>> for doc in db.find():
...     db.update({'_id': doc['_id']},
...         {'$set': {'name':doc['q0']['Results'][0]['Name']}, upsert=False, multi=False})
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> for doc in db.find():
...     db.update({'_id': doc['_id']},
...         {'$set': {'name':doc['q0']['Results'][0]['Name']}, upsert=False, multi=False})
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    {'$set': {'name':doc['q0']['Results'][0]['Name']}, upsert=False, multi=False})
```

Comment: Tu problema es el corchete, debería ser: `db.update({'_id': doc['_id']},{'$set':{'name':doc['q0']['Results'][0]['Name']}}, upsert=False, multi=False)`

Comment: @César Cuando dices corchete, supongo que te refieres a la llave.

Comment: @DanteS. sí, lo siento. Me refería a la llave, estaba en mala posición.

Comment: @César no hay de que disculparse c: Son solo errores, yo solo quería aclarartelo.